# Mathematically, is there a highest possible compression level for given data?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assuming we found a perfect lossless data compression algorithm, can we prove that this algorithm would only be able to compress given data to a certain size?

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849878/measure-of-information-in-a-particular-example/2849907) I just wrote for a different question -- it's not about a proof, but it addresses some to the issues involved.

Comment: You are likely reaching toward the concept of Kolmogorov complexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: @CoryGriffith I just wanted to post this link as well :)

Comment: What do you mean by "perfect"?  Gives best compression for all inputs (which is easy to show is impossible)?  Gives lowest average output length for inputs of length $n$, for all $n$ (which counterintuitively is achieved by the identity function, i.e. no compression at all)?  Or something else?

Comment: @DanielSchepler By perfect, I mean an algorithm such that no greater level of data compression could be possible without the compression becoming lossy.